# PHP - Correctly check if a date is older than two months

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I need to set an user meta field in user meta table of wordpress. This field will contain a date, that will be set at the fisrt login of the user otherwise the field when the user register will be empty.

I'm trying with this code, but I've noticed that the date is wrong. I need to check if the date is less that 60 days or if the field is empty

```php
<?php
$usermeta = get_user_meta( $user->ID );

if( empty($usermeta['last_pwd_reset'][0]) || $usermeta['last_pwd_reset'][0] < date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+2 months',strtotime($usermeta['last_pwd_reset'][0]))) ){
 // other code stuff here
}  
?>
```

How I can correctly get the actual date in the format `d/m/Y` and how I can check if the date is older that two months?

My last test with the following code on phpfiddle give me a worng result

```php
<?php
$now = '02/08/2022';

echo 'date is older than two months ' . date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+2 months',strtotime($now)));
echo 'actual date '. date('d/m/Y');
?>
// echo results
//date is older than two months 08/04/2022
//actual date 02/10/2022
```

I'm doing this check into the `login_redirect` filter inside my custom plugin. Someone suggested me to use the `wp_login` action but I'm redirecting the users based on the assigned role so I'm not sure if the `wp_login` can fit my needings.

Answer (score 1):

So PHP seems like dates with a `/` be stored as an American format and dates with a `-` to be stored as the European format.

So a simple fix would be to simply store your  `$now = '02/08/2022';` as `$now = '02-08-2022';` instead.

But lets say you already have all your `$now` dates stored they way they are, you can simple add a something like `$now2 = str_replace("/","-",$now);` to just programmatically do it.

Give this code a try and see if it works for you:

```
$now = '02/08/2022';
$now2 = str_replace("/","-",$now);

echo 'date is older than two months ' . date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+2 months',strtotime($now2)));
echo 'actual date '. date('d/m/Y');
```

EDIT:  In order to properly check if a date is older than 2 months, try this code:

```
$usermeta = get_user_meta( $user->ID );
$dateString = str_replace("/","-", $usermeta['last_pwd_reset'][0]);
$lastReset = strtotime($dateString);

if( empty($usermeta['last_pwd_reset'][0]) || ($lastReset < strtotime("-2 months"))){
 // other code stuff here
}
```

Comment: I will get the date using php, in the example I've used a sample date, but in my code this will be managed from the `date()` function of php. Do I need to set the timezone to europe?

Comment: How are you storing the date in your db? Is it an actual timestamp or is it a string such as `02/08/2022`?

Comment: I will pass the result from the `date('d-m-Y')` or `new DateTime()` after applied formatting to the `add_user_meta()` function of wordpress. I think it will be stored as a string.

Comment: @newbiedev I have updated my answer which should get you where you need to be.

Comment: ok, Just a question about the check. Why the difference is calculated between the dates using the `-2 months`? With the `new DateTime('2-5-2022')` and the `diff()` function of the class I will get the difference between the passed date and a an interval set into anoter istance of the class like `new DateTime('+ 2 months')`. Can be this reliable ?

Comment: There's more than 1 way to arrive at the same answer. In your question you said "I need to check if the date is less that 60 days or if the field is empty" and my code will do exactly that. the code: `strtotime("-2 months")` gives us a timestamp exactly 2 months ago from right now.  I check if `$lastReset` is before that or not.  if its before, then it has been at least 60 days since someone reset their password.

Comment: ok, so I assume I'm doing it wrong by adding `+ 2 months` to the current date and check the difference with the date stored into the database?

Comment: The check is agains the stored date that will expire the password after two months, so I was supposing that I had to add two months to the current date?

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly sure you are comparing 2 bits of text that happen to hold a date, that sometimes work, but it is better to make 2 dates and compare them, of in this case get the difference between the 2 dates

```
/*
    strings holding dates may sometimes compare as expected but more than often they will not
*/

$last_pwd_reset = '02/08/2022'; // $usermeta['last_pwd_reset'][0]
// convert to a date using correct format
$last_reset = (new DateTimeImmutable())->createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $last_pwd_reset);

$interval = $last_reset->diff(new DateTimeImmutable('now - 2 months'));
if ( $interval->days > 0 ) {
    // password needs reset
    echo 'reset password';
} else {
    echo 'no reset required';
}
```

Comment: I will test your suggestion. I need to implement this in a wp function

Comment: Its PHP so is WP

Comment: what this line does exactly? will it check if the passed date created using `date('d-m-Y')` in php is older of two months?
`$interval = $last_reset->diff(new DateTimeImmutable('now - 2 months'));`

Comment: It takes the last reset date and compares it with a date 2 months ago, and creates an interval (number of days difference) So if the number of days, in the interval object is greater than zero you need to chnage the password